How to run handlers if one loop item change?
Is it possible to run a handler if a tasks is failing, but ignore_errors?
If you have a tasks running in a loop and one element in the loop is failing, notify is ignored.
I would like to execute the handler if at least one of my element changed.
- name: Test handlers
  ansible.builtin.command: ls "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "/bin"
    - "/wrongFolder"
  ignore_errors: true
  notify: Reboot serve

In this case, I will have a change on the item bin and a failed on wrongFolder, so, in that case, handler is not executed.
Is it possible to change that and execute the handler if one item change?

Short answer: Replace ignore_errors: true by failed_when: false
Details: How do the attributes changed and failed work in a loop?

The attributes changed and failed are present in all items
If any item changed the aggregate attribute changed is True
If any item failed the aggregate attribute failed is True
If any item failed (the aggregate attribute failed is True) and the handler is not notified
If no item failed the aggregate attribute failed is missing

For example,
  - command: "{{ item }}"
    loop: ['true', 'true']
    register: out
    ignore_errors: true
    notify: Reboot

  - debug:
      msg: |
        out.changed: {{ out.changed }}
        out.failed: {{ out.failed | d('UNDEF') }}
        out.results[].rc: {{ out.results | json_query('[].rc') }}
        out.results[].changed: {{ out.results | json_query('[].changed') }}
        out.results[].failed: {{ out.results | json_query('[].failed') }}

the result is changed and the handler is notified
    out.changed: True
    out.failed: UNDEF
    out.results[].rc: [0, 0]
    out.results[].changed: [True, True]
    out.results[].failed: [False, False]

If any item failed
  - command: "{{ item }}"
    loop: ['true', 'false']
    register: out
    ignore_errors: true
    notify: Reboot

the result is changed, but the handler is not notified because the result failed
    out.changed: True
    out.failed: True
    out.results[].rc: [0, 1]
    out.results[].changed: [True, True]
    out.results[].failed: [False, True]

If you want to notify a handler you have to set failed_when: false (instead of ignore_errors: true)
  - command: "{{ item }}"
    loop: ['true', 'false']
    register: out
    failed_when: false
    notify: Reboot

the result is changed, failed is undefined, and the handler is notified
    out.changed: True
    out.failed: UNDEF
    out.results[].rc: [0, 1]
    out.results[].changed: [True, True]
    out.results[].failed: [False, False]


You can either have the following in your ansible.cfg file1:
[defaults]

# ... some other stuff ...

force_handlers = true

# ... rest of the file

Or, run your playbook with --force-handlers flag such as below:
ansible-playbook --force-handlers playbook.yml

